# Need to calculate average per user for a 30 day history for each user using hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata

I am confused about my datamodel. i.e if I need to use a UDAF to solve this and how hive deals with this when it comes down to splitting the task.

Problem statement: I need to compute the average(slightly different version then what is available so it needs to be a custom formula) per user based on events that are from 30 days as I look back in time. So I have my data in the form of:

> userid date counts
>   user1  day30  34
>   user1  day30  23
>   user1  day4   22
>   user1  day1   21
>   user2  day30  23
>   user2  day23  12
>   usern ....

What I need as a ouput is the following:

> user1 avg: (34+23+22+21...)/30
>   user2 avg: (23+12...)/30

What is the most memory efficient way to approach this problem? I probably need to use a udf but how does this work with a user with a lot of rows? Does the UDAF deal with this per user or do I need to do something like restrict all rows pertaining to one user in a reducer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the challange here i used the sample data as below:

```
userid,date1,counts
user1,day30,34
user1,day30,23
user1,day4,22
user1,day1,21
user2,day30,23
user2,day23,12
```

and below is the table defination

```
create external table table1 (
 userid string,
 date1 string,
 counts int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/tmp/tempd';
```

and the query is:

```
select userid , sum(counts)/30 
from table1 
group by userid;
```

*Output*

```
user1   3.3333333333333335
user2   1.1666666666666667
```

let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: my average is a weighted average calculated differently so it needs to be a udaf...and the data will be a lot more which will be in memory. I just want to know what the best practices are for a situation like that. As in do we do any query optimization things, order by userids etc

Comment: the users themselves will be almost around 10 million so thats a lot of data going in.

Comment: @Roshini i was thinking more on query part rather on memory, and if you have a different subset of data which can represent the whole data and its variation so provide it to me i can give it a try...